# Metodo recursivo con ArrayList en java

Tags: java

Buenas, estoy en medio de un problema con un ejercicio de una tarea.

tengo una clase como esta:

**UML de la clase**

[image: UML DE LA CLASE]

Y tengo que armar un método publico recursivo, que devuelva un ArrayList con la cantidad total de sub sectores (teniendo en cuenta que cada sub sector puede tener a su vez sub sectores)

**La clase (además de los metodos get and set que no los pegue para no llenar tanto de código)**

```
public class Sector {

private int numero;
private String denominacion;
private String tipo;

private ArrayList<Sector> sectores = new ArrayList<>();   

public Sector(int numero, String denominacion, String tipo) {
    this.numero = numero;
    this.denominacion = denominacion;
    this.tipo = tipo;
}
```

**Este es el código del método**

```
public ArrayList<Sector> obtenerTotalSubsectores(Sector sector, ArrayList<Sector> sectores) {
    sectores.add(this);
        if (sector.getSectores() != null) {
            for(Sector sector1 : sector.getSectores()) {
                obtenerTotalSubsectores(sector1, sectores);
            }
        }        
    return sectores;
}
```

**y el código del main**

```
    Sector s1 = new Sector(100, "sales", "sales");
    Sector s1_1 = new Sector (101, "minor sales", "minor");
    Sector s1_2 = new Sector (102, "mayor sales", "mayor");
    Sector s1_2_1 = new Sector (102, "lala sales", "lalala");

    s1.getSectores().add(s1_1);
    s1.getSectores().add(s1_2);
    s1_2.getSectores().add(s1_2_1);

    Sector s2 = new Sector(200, "Sistemas", "sistemas");        
    Sector s2_1 = new Sector(200, "Soporte Técnico", "soporte");

    s2.getSectores().add(s2_1);
    s1.getSectores().add(s2);   

    s1.obtenerTotalSubsectores(s1, s1.getSectores());
```

**y el error que me tira**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
at ejercicio_c_actividad.Sector.obtenerTotalSubsectores(Sector.java:79)
at ejercicio_c_actividad.Main.main(Main.java:61)
C:\xxx\xxx\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

¿Alguna idea de qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## SOLUCION A TU CODIGO

Tenes dos fallos, primero de todo, aunque seria lo correcto, no puedes añadir `this` a cada recursion, porque el metodo lo ejecuta un `Sector` y le pasas otro!!!! Así añadirás el mismo a cada vuelta, ignorando el sector a procesar en si. Por lo que:

```
public ArrayList<Sector> obtenerTotalSubsectores(Sector sector, ArrayList<Sector> sectores) {
    sectores.add(sector);
    if (sector.getSectores() != null) {
        for (Sector sector1 : sector.getSectores()) {
            obtenerTotalSubsectores(sector1, sectores);
        }
    }
    return sectores;
}
```

El segundo es que envias un `ArrayList` de sectores lleno, cosa que no tiene mucha logica, debes crear un nuevo objeto a rellenar, modificando tu main:

```
ArrayList<Sector> sectores = new ArrayList<Sector>();
s1.obtenerTotalSubsectores(s1, sectores);


System.out.println("TOTAL SECTORES EN EL " + s1.getNumero());
for (Sector s : sectores) {
    System.out.println(s.toString());
}

sectores.clear();
s2.obtenerTotalSubsectores(s2, sectores);

System.out.println("\n\nTOTAL SECTORES EN EL " + s2.getNumero());
for (Sector s : sectores) {
    System.out.println(s.toString());
}
```

Tenemos esta salida (he añadido un `toString()` estandard para comprobar las salidas mas facilmente)

```
TOTAL SECTORES EN EL 100
Sector [numero=100, denominacion=sales, tipo=sales, sectores=[Sector [numero=101, denominacion=minor sales, tipo=minor, sectores=[]], Sector [numero=102, denominacion=mayor sales, tipo=mayor, sectores=[Sector [numero=102, denominacion=lala sales, tipo=lalala, sectores=[]]]], Sector [numero=200, denominacion=Sistemas, tipo=sistemas, sectores=[Sector [numero=201, denominacion=Soporte Técnico, tipo=soporte, sectores=[]]]]]]
Sector [numero=101, denominacion=minor sales, tipo=minor, sectores=[]]
Sector [numero=102, denominacion=mayor sales, tipo=mayor, sectores=[Sector [numero=102, denominacion=lala sales, tipo=lalala, sectores=[]]]]
Sector [numero=102, denominacion=lala sales, tipo=lalala, sectores=[]]
Sector [numero=200, denominacion=Sistemas, tipo=sistemas, sectores=[Sector [numero=201, denominacion=Soporte Técnico, tipo=soporte, sectores=[]]]]
Sector [numero=201, denominacion=Soporte Técnico, tipo=soporte, sectores=[]]


TOTAL SECTORES EN EL 200
Sector [numero=200, denominacion=Sistemas, tipo=sistemas, sectores=[Sector [numero=201, denominacion=Soporte Técnico, tipo=soporte, sectores=[]]]]
Sector [numero=201, denominacion=Soporte Técnico, tipo=soporte, sectores=[]]
```

---

## SOLUCION CORRECTA

Ahora bien, aclarado en que estas fallando, creo que no estas utilizando la recursion correctamente, me explico, ya que el metodo lo tiene el `Sector`, no tienes porque pasarselo al metodo cada vez, ya que se ejecutara dentro del mismo, solo necesitas pasar la lista a rellenar.

Para no liarme, ni liarte más, veamos el codigo:

```
public ArrayList<Sector> obtenerTotalSubsectores(ArrayList<Sector> sectores) {
    sectores.add(this);
    if (this.getSectores() != null) {
        for (Sector sector1 : this.getSectores()) {
            sector1.obtenerTotalSubsectores(sectores);
        }
    }
    return sectores;
}
```

Ahora si que puedes añadir `this`  ya que la recursion se esta ejecutando correctamente desde el sector procesado en ese momento, descargando el metodo de un atributo y clarificando el codigo (aunque aumentando la abstraccion)

El mismo main modificado quedaria asi:

```
ArrayList<Sector> sectores = new ArrayList<Sector>();
s1.obtenerTotalSubsectores(sectores);


System.out.println("TOTAL SECTORES EN EL " + s1.getNumero());
for (Sector s : sectores) {
    System.out.println(s.toString());
}

sectores.clear();
s2.obtenerTotalSubsectores(sectores);

System.out.println("\n\nTOTAL SECTORES EN EL " + s2.getNumero());
for (Sector s : sectores) {
    System.out.println(s.toString());
}
```

Y nos daría el mismo resultado:

```
TOTAL SECTORES EN EL 100
Sector [numero=100, denominacion=sales, tipo=sales, sectores=[Sector [numero=101, denominacion=minor sales, tipo=minor, sectores=[]], Sector [numero=102, denominacion=mayor sales, tipo=mayor, sectores=[Sector [numero=102, denominacion=lala sales, tipo=lalala, sectores=[]]]], Sector [numero=200, denominacion=Sistemas, tipo=sistemas, sectores=[Sector [numero=201, denominacion=Soporte Técnico, tipo=soporte, sectores=[]]]]]]
Sector [numero=101, denominacion=minor sales, tipo=minor, sectores=[]]
Sector [numero=102, denominacion=mayor sales, tipo=mayor, sectores=[Sector [numero=102, denominacion=lala sales, tipo=lalala, sectores=[]]]]
Sector [numero=102, denominacion=lala sales, tipo=lalala, sectores=[]]
Sector [numero=200, denominacion=Sistemas, tipo=sistemas, sectores=[Sector [numero=201, denominacion=Soporte Técnico, tipo=soporte, sectores=[]]]]
Sector [numero=201, denominacion=Soporte Técnico, tipo=soporte, sectores=[]]


TOTAL SECTORES EN EL 200
Sector [numero=200, denominacion=Sistemas, tipo=sistemas, sectores=[Sector [numero=201, denominacion=Soporte Técnico, tipo=soporte, sectores=[]]]]
Sector [numero=201, denominacion=Soporte Técnico, tipo=soporte, sectores=[]]
```

Comment: Tu respuesta es 100% correcta :). Simplemente me gustaría añadir que no estaría de más utilizar [iteradores](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18448671/how-to-avoid-concurrentmodificationexception-while-removing-elements-from-arr/18448699#18448699)

Comment: @miquel la verdad es que para la recursion están bien ya que tienes un mayor control de lo que ocurre, pasa que no soy muy fan suyo y si puedo iterar a *manurrio*, pues mejor `:P`

Comment: Si, viendo el código entendí que lo habia planteado mal desde el principio con los atributos